# Flutter error when sending post request (even with correct data)

Tags: flutter, rest, flask, http-post, get-request

I have a code where I use http package in flutter to post request from a Fake API, which I found using the website mocki.io. The problem is that whenever I put the correct data, it keeps giving me response.statusCode = 405.

http_service.dart (post request)

```
class HttpService {

  static const _loginUrl = 'https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8';

  static login(cpf, password, context) async {
    Map<String, String> request = {"name": cpf, "city": password};
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(_loginUrl),
      body: jsonEncode(request),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
    } else {
      await EasyLoading.showError(
          "Error Code : ${response.statusCode.toString()} $cpf $password");
    }
  }
}
```

Inserting the data, according to the fake mocki API:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxsFI.png)
Error presented:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYa8U.png)

I would like some help with using Rest API, Flutter and Flask =D. I'll be grateful to those who can send me links about that subject (courses, videos etc).

I tried reading lots of blogs about that same subject, none helped. As I'm novice to that area. =(

Comment: 405 error means target resource doesn't support this method, in this case POST method

Comment: This seems like a problem at your REST API endpoint not handling this POST request properly. Do also provide what you have at your flask backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Website you use for creating mock/fake apis mocki.io. As Of now it's only allow
`GET` request you cannot `POST` on it.

And You are just doing that just send request with `GET` method and it will work as expected.

Here's An Example (using postman):

`GET REQUEST`
[image]

And now your `API` calling method will be

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HttpService {
  static const _loginUrl =
      'https://mocki.io/v1/d4867d8b-b5d5-4a48-a4ab-79131b5809b8';

  static login() async {
    try {
      // get request
      final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(_loginUrl),
      );

      print('responseCode : ${response.statusCode}');
      print('responseBody : ${response.body}');
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('result : $result');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error : $e');
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Thank you

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot. Didn't know mocki only accepts get requests.